# SignalR WebSocket can connect from NodeJs to DotNet Core?

Tags: node.js, .net, angular, axios, signalr

I have a scenario.

**Angular**  ->  *NodeJs*  ->  **DotNetCore**

> Client Application communicate to NodeJS and then to DotNet Core Api .

And my SignalR hub in the API, Which can be connected in Angular. But, I need to connect it from NodeJS ( Axios )

Not having success to do so.

```
    this._hubCon = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl(`${NodeJsAppUrl}/Hub`, { transport: HttpTransportType.WebSockets } as IHttpConnectionOptions)
    .configureLogging(LogLevel.Debug)
    .build();
```

and its not negotiating. showing error

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:111/NodeJsApp/Hub' failed.
> and
> Error: Unable to initialize any of the available transports.